# Pass generated request header from an HttpServletRequestWrapper to the next jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httprequest

I created a Servlet Filter in order to simulate a proxy server where request will be passed to and will return a request with additional headers. The filter simply wraps an HttpServletRequestWrapper to the request and adds additional headers. This process is performed on the server portal where users will be redirected to from an external system.

Currently, I am able to create the additional headers; however, I do not know how to pass these headers, to the succeeding jsp pages using my filter. Any ideas on how to do this? Note that this is just to simulate the server that would add the additional headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the wrapped request to the filter chain:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                     ServletResponse response, 
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = wrapOriginalRequestToAddHeaders(request);
    chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not really the solution to the problem I am looking for. What I intend to do is something like this:
User Logs In -> Filter (Put in username header in request) -> Redirected to Homepage -> (When user clicks a link and get redirected) Filter, somehow get username header and put it again in the next request. Is there someway to do this without directly storing it in the client's memory like cookies? Could I do something with the HTTPServletResponse so that the username header gets passed to the server?

Comment: That's what cookies are for. I don't see any other way.